# Remotely install apps on android from the web-based market

Tags: javascript, android, selenium, google-play

I want to install let's say all of the top-100-free applications of the market on my android phone. I know this is doable by hand directly on the phone or with the web version of the market.
Anyway, I try to automate this process.

I initially thought about using libraries such as selenium, mechanize or httpUnit to programatically interact with the web-based market. But the code of the page is pretty obscure (due to some optimization/offuscation in the Javascript part) and I can't really figure out how to build the right requests to make it.

By the way, I am ready to root my phone. Does anybody have an idea how to do it?

### Edit

**Beware, don't try to do this, this is illegal**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anybody have an idea how to do it?

You don't, because doing so would violate the Android Market [Site Terms of Service](http://www.google.com/mobile/android/market-tos.html):

> 3.3    You agree not to access (or attempt to access) the Market by any means other than through the interface that is provided by Google, unless you have been specifically allowed to do so in a separate agreement with Google. You specifically agree not to access (or attempt to access) the Market through any automated means (including use of scripts, crawlers, or similar technologies) and shall ensure that you comply with the instructions set out in any robots.txt file present on the Market website.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with Selenium? A Google Market screen scraper is your best bet.

Don't try to work with JavaScript directly - work with HTML elements. If a button invokes a JavaScript function, rather than emulating said JavaScript, emulate a button click.

You can build a screen scraper with the Microsoft Web Browser Control (AKA "IE engine") fairly quick. The core idea is - don't emulate a Web browser, use a ready made, programmable one. Yes, the code will probably need a GUI system to run - won't be a daemon.

Comment: That should certainly work, but I didn't know that it was not right to do so.